# Which Osterwalder-Schrader axiom does a tree-level QFT violate?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

(I think this question is really about *any* truncation of the perturbation series, but I want to avoid having to think hard, so I'll talk about tree-level only to ask the question.)

Let's start with scalar field theory in $d$ spacetime dimensions, with an action:

$$
S = \int d^d\! x\; \frac 1 2 \phi(m^2 - \partial^2)\phi + \lambda \phi^4
$$

With $\lambda=0$, we can compute the free-theory correlation functions $\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle_0$, $\langle\phi(w)\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z)\rangle_0$, and so on. Turning on the interaction introduces divergences, but let's avoid that conversation entirely by expanding each correlation function to leading order in $\hbar^{-1}$. The two-point function is unchanged, the four-point function picks up a contact term, and so on. This is the theory I want to consider: correlation functions are given by tree-level diagrams. (I'm assuming it's clear what Feynman diagrams contribute. If it's not, I'll try and add pictures.)

*Edit: or, consider the theory just at leading order in $\lambda$. Or, leave the 2-point function free, and expand all higher-order correlations to first order in $\lambda$. See comments below for why.*

One additional caveat: I'm going evaluate at $\lambda < 0$ (but $\lambda$ need not be small -- let's say $\lambda = -1$). I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary, but it seems to be sufficient to protect OS positivity.

This isn't a free theory, so there should be something sick about it (just because it's too easy). At least, it seems to violate unitarity. The OS axioms imply, among other things, a unitary representation of the Lorentz group, so this theory must also violate one of them. The question is, which one? (In principle, this could be discovered by carefully following the proof, but much of the proof is technical and over my head, at least for the amount of time I'd like to spend on this.)

That's the question. Here's my inadequate attempt to answer it.

Following the labeling in the Osterwalder-Schrader papers ([1](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103858969), [2](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103899050)):

**E0 (Distributions):** This condition had to be changed to fix an error, and the second paper replaces it with three possibilities. As nearly as I can tell, the original form of E0 is obeyed by the construction above, but I'm not confident I've understood any of the other three.

**E1 (Euclidean Invariance):** Trivially obeyed. That's one of the nice things about perturbation theory.

**E2 (Positivity):** I would have *thought* this was where the problem lay, as I understood positivity to be closely related to unitarity. OS only requires that certain correlation functions be positive (in order for the Hilbert space to have a norm), but *all* the correlation functions are strictly positive if we take $\lambda < 0$. I don't know if positivity is obeyed with $\lambda > 0$.

**E3 (Symmetry):** This is symmetry under permutations of the fields in the expectation value. Again, trivially obeyed.

**E4 (Cluster property):** Because of the way we constructed the green's functions, each is naturally decomposed into a connected piece and a disconnected piece. The connected pieces decay exponentially with the separation of operators, and that's cluster decomposition.

If I had to guess: with $\lambda > 0$, E2 is violated, and with negative coupling, the stronger regularity requirements of the second paper are violated.  But, it's always possible I misunderstood E2 or E4. Or maybe it's always the stronger requirements on the distribution.

(If the stronger requirements on the distribution were all that separated tree-level QFTs from real ones, surely somebody would have written a paper pointing this out, as an explicit example of why the strengthened axioms of OS II are necessary. I can't find this paper.)

Comment: I'm not sure you can give a full answer to this question while only considering tree level diagrams. For example, a standard way to check unitarity is to use the optical theorem, which relates diagrams of loop order $N$ with "cuts" to squares of diagrams of loop order $N-1$ (so for instance unitarity relates 1-loop diagrams and tree diagrams). Additionally, one can say anomalies (classical symmetries violated at the quantum level) arise from the failure to find a regulator which obeys a given symmetry; this kind of subtlety only arises at 1 loop or higher.

Comment: @Andrew The restriction to tree-level diagrams isn't meant to be an approximation -- it's a definition of a set of correlation functions. Those correlation functions clearly don't give a unitary QFT (so that Wightman axiom is obviously violated). It follows that they must violate at least one OS axiom. The question is, which?

Comment: Do the OS axioms imply a *separable* Hilbert space? The tree-level approximation is the classical approximation. Classical field theory can be regarded as a special case of quantum field theory in which all observables commute with each other, the only problem being that the Hilbert space can't be separable in the classical case. So maybe "too easy" isn't a good reason to think a non-free theory must violate an OS axiom. Maybe the only sickness is that the Hilbert space isn't separable. Is that a possibility?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly yikes -- I don't _think_ OS implies separable Hilbert space. You're asserting that the tree-level theory is in fact unitary, right? Thinking about it as a taylor expansion of $e^{-i H t / \hbar}$, that surprises me.

Comment: It's worth noting that the same argument works if I expand in $\lambda$ instead of $\hbar^{-1}$. This is no longer a classical theory, and Peskin explicitly claims it isn't unitary, so I'm still convinced there's a puzzle...

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly do you have a reference for a precise formulation of a classical theory in terms of non-separable Hilbert space and operators?

Comment: For what it's worth, I do think that OS imply separable Hilbert space, although I'm not 100% sure. First of all, one should note that OS do not talk about a Hilbert space. However, one can reconstruct a Hilbert space. The way the reconstruction is done is that as states one considers formal linear combinations of products of the fundamental field integrated against certain test functions, and then possible null states are removed and the space is completed. Since the space of test functions is separable, I'm pretty sure one can explicitly construct a dense countable set of states.

Comment: However, separability is unlikely to be the issue. For one thing, already the free theory two-point function shows that commutators are non-vanishing.

Comment: Also, OS positivity is not just positivity of correlation functions, it is positivity of integrals of correlation functions, which is much, much more non-trivial. For example in $d$ dimensions, the scalar two-point function given by $1/|x|^\Delta$ is positive for any $\Delta$, but it is OS-positive only for $\Delta\geq \frac{d-2}{2}$ (or $\Delta=0$). I would think positivity is what is violated, although I don't know of the precise way it happens.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk okay, your last point (positivity of integrals of correlators) could be the resolution, but I don't understand it! Where does the bound of $\Delta \ge \frac{d-2}{2}$ come from? Is this convergence of some integral?

Comment: @ScottLawrence There is no convergence issue because the integrals are taken away from coincident points. To see that OS-positivity fails for $\Delta<\frac{d-2}{2}$ you can check that the two-point function of $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi(x)$ fails to be positive. The reason why this contradicts OS-positivity is that you can choose the test function in OS-positivity statement to approximate $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \delta^d(x-x_0)$. (By the way, I've made a typo and the above condition is for $1/|x|^{2\Delta}$.)

Comment: @ScottLawrence proving that for $\Delta\geq \frac{d-2}{2}$ the two-point function is OS-positive is a bit more non-trivial and involves rewriting the two-point function as a Laplace-Fourier transform of some function and checking that this function is positive point-wise.

Comment: Folks! See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580440/for-which-values-of-lambda-the-euclidean-two-point-function-p2-m2-lambd/580541#580541 Peter is correct in pointing out that E2 is more complicated than pointwise positivity which would be fixed by $\lambda<0$. However, Scott is also correct in that indirectly an integrability condition hides behind the lower bound on $\Delta$.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Oh! I was failing to think about general distributions. I get it now, thanks.